# Courier or carrier?

Tags: word-usage

What is the more correct name for postal services such as USPS (United States Postal Service), UPS (United Parcel Service), and FedEx (Federal Express)—*carriers* or *couriers*?

If I name them as **carriers**, is it okay to name delivery status as **carrier status**? Or the better naming is: **carrier service** and **carrier status**?

Comment: They are *[common carriers (see last para of Transportation Firms)](https://www.britannica.com/topic/marketing/Market-research-firms#ref394093)*. Couriers are something different. Do use common carrier, because just plain carrier really doesn't mean anything in the business.

Comment: UPS is a delivery service, using its own carriers (transportation carriers, i.e. here, planes) and it is not a courier service, which means a service using a person who delivers documents using various means of transportation such as a motorbike or bicycle or even an airplane. Remember: international couriers? No longer, alas. It used to be a really cheap way to travel around the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them *carry* stuff, and can therefore be called *carriers*, as is true of trucking companies, airlines, and so forth. When arranging for shipment of goods with someone, one may thus ask ‘Which carrier will you use for the shipment?’ Possible answers to that question include all of the companies mentioned by the OP.

While some definitions of the word *courier* make it appear interchangeable with *carrier*, its typical contemporary usage is limited to the companies that claim to provide faster, better service than the mail; it thus excludes the postal service. Asking someone ‘Which courier will you use for the shipment?’ will generally be understood to imply that one expects the answer to be something like UPS or FedEx, and *not* USPS. (Incidentally, UPS, FedEx, and suchlike would not normally be called *postal* services; that term is reserved for the USPS and its counterparts in other countries.)

Comment: I wouldn't count UPS or FedEx as a courier service; to me, *courier* in the context of shipping strongly implies that the same individual will carry the package from door-to-door.

Comment: So I can say about them just carriers? Without type or anything?

Comment: @1006a, This may have been an implication in the past, but is not so any more, certainly not a strong one. In fact, a present-day businessperson who needs a service of the kind you describe is more likely to use the word *messenger* (e.g. ‘This document is very important; please send it by a special messenger.’).

Comment: @VadimGalygin, Yes. One wouldn't normally say that UPS is a carrier type; it is a carrier.